# Problems when implementing Keras model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm just starting off with `Tensorflow`.

I tried implementing a model to classify digits in the MNSIT dataset.

I am familiar with `Keras`, so I first used it to create the model.

Keras code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.datasets import mnist
from os import path

import numpy as np

network = Sequential()
network.add(Dense(700, input_dim=784, activation='tanh'))
network.add(Dense(500, activation='tanh'))
network.add(Dense(500, activation='tanh'))
network.add(Dense(500, activation='tanh'))
network.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

network.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

(x_train, y_temp), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
y_train = vectorize(y_temp)  # I defined this function to create vectors of the labels. It works without issues.

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2])

network.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=3)

x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1]*x_test.shape[2])


scores = network.predict(x_test)

correct_pred = 0
for i in range(len(scores)):
    if np.argmax(scores[i]) == y_test[i]:
        correct_pred += 1

print((correct_pred/len(scores))*100)
```

The above code gives me an accuracy of around 92%.

I tried implementing the same model in Tensorflow:

```
import sys

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

data = input_data.read_data_sets('.', one_hot=True)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 700]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([700, 500]))
w3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500, 500]))
w4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500, 500]))
w5 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500, 10]))

h1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(x, w))
h2 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(h1, w2))
h3 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(h2, w3))
h4 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(h3, w4))
h = tf.matmul(h4, w5)

loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=h, labels=y))
gradient_descent = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

correct_mask = tf.equal(tf.argmax(h, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_mask, tf.float32))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(3):
    batch_x, batch_y = data.train.next_batch(100)
    loss_print = tf.print(loss, output_stream=sys.stdout)
    sess.run([gradient_descent, loss_print], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

ans = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: data.test.images, y: data.test.labels})

print(ans)
```

However, this code only gave me an accuracy of around 11%.
I tried increasing the number of epochs to 1000, but the result didn't change. Furthermore, the loss in every epoch was the same (2.30).

Am I missing something in the Tensorflow code?

Comment: One issue is that you have not considered the bias variables of Dense layers in your TF model.

Comment: The bias values are all zero. Does it still make a difference if I don't include them?

Comment: They are initially zero, but during training they change like the kernel weights. That's why they are called **variables** not constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was that I initialized the weights as zeros!

Simply changing

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 700]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([700, 500]))
w3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500, 500]))
w4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500, 500]))
w5 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500, 10]))
```

to

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 700], seed=42))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([700, 500], seed=42))
w3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500, 500], seed=42))
w4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500, 500], seed=42))
w5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500, 10], seed=42))
```

gave significant improvements.